# Creating new Profilepath for AD User

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm making a script in which a new AD user gets created. I also want to give it a Profilepath and a Homepath. But I always get a error when I run this part were I try to create a new Profilepath and Homepath. Thats my Script:

```
$StandardPath = "\\192.168.1.32\Users\"
$ProfilePath = “\\192.168.1.32\Users\$($Username)"
$HomePath = “\\192.168.1\Users\$($Username)\Home"

New-Item -path $StandardPath -Name $Username -ItemType Directory -force
Set-ADUser $Username -ProfilePath $ProfilePath
New-Item -path $Profilepath -Name "Home" -ItemType Directory -force
Set-ADUser $Username -HomeDrive $driveLetter -HomeDirectory $HomePath
```

And here Is the Error:

```
New-Item : The path is not of a legal form.
At C:\Users\ewzadmin\Desktop\AddADUsers.ps1:47 char:9
+         New-Item -path $StandardPath -Name $Username -ItemType Direct ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\192.168.1.32\Users:String) [New-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Aren't you forgetting the driveletter in the $StandardPath? ``"\\192.168.1.32\$driveLetter\Users"`` ? P.S. better not use (in this case mix) curly quotes `“` and always use straight quotes instead. Also make sure your variable `$Username` does not contain invalid foldername characters

Comment: Omg yeah you are right about the driveletter, I completly forgot about that.

Comment: Don't forget the administrative drive-letter shares are suffixed with a `$` too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things going on here:

- You need to specify the share name in the UNC path between the server name and share path. Administrative shares are automatically created for attached storage by default (such as for the `C:`), and the drive letter is suffixed with a `$`.

  - You do not need to escape the `$` since the proceeding `\` will not be parsed as part of a variable name
- You forgot the last octet of the IP when setting `$HomePath`
- While not an issue, we can use the `$StandardPath` variable to build the other two
- Both `New-Item` invocations can omit the `-Name` parameter since you have the directory paths specified in the `-Path` variable. Using the `-Name` parameter will create *another* directory under the directory specified in `-Path`, which will already create any missing directories.
- You can also simply use `$ProfilePath` to create the `$Username` directory, since the path is the same as `$StandardPath\$Username`
- You don't need to use `$($Username)` for expanding a single variable. You can omit the sub-expression operator `$()` entirely.

The below corrections should work for you:

> Warning: If you must use roaming profiles, back them by `DFS` or at least a proper storage appliance, not a `CIFS` share from a single server. Also don't use the IP, use the `NetBIOS`, `DNS`, or `FQDN` name in the `UNC` path. If that server goes down or the IP changes your user on that system will have issues the profile not synchronizing correctly, and roaming profiles can be fickle when it comes to sync issues.

```
$StandardPath = "\\192.168.1.32\$driveletter$\Users"
$ProfilePath = "$StandardPath\$Username"
$HomePath = “$ProfilePath\Home"

New-Item -Path $ProfilePath -ItemType Directory -Force
Set-ADUser $Username -ProfilePath $ProfilePath
New-Item -Path $ProfilePath -ItemType Directory -Force
Set-ADUser $Username -HomeDrive $driveLetter -HomeDirectory $HomePath
```